# Convert text string to Decimal or currency type for ms-access query in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I want to run a query that converts the text from the field into a number or currency field.

I have a query like :

```
SELECT * FROM qryProjectData ORDER BY prj.ProjectDisplayNo
```

I have data like.

```
362
362.01
362.2
362.3
362.4
362.5
362.6
362.7
362.8
362.9
362.10
362.11
```

I did sorting on it But result is like below.

```
362
362.01
362.10
362.11
362.2
362.3
362.4
362.5
362.6
362.7
362.8
362.9
```

Problem is it is text field, that why not sorting properly.
Need to convert it into Decimal or currency type.

Help me, if anyone have solution.

Comment: Any reason you don't have it as a decimal field in the database already?

Comment: There is a lots of data... so, now i cant change it

Comment: Changing it now may take a while (but should be automatable) - but unless you're planning on throwing it away after this task, you'll reap the benefits in the long term.

Comment: If I change the type in database, data must lost....

Comment: Why? Is some of the data *not* genuinely numeric? If so, you need to consider that in your ordering... how would you expect that to be handled?

Comment: If you store your data corrrectly, all these problems vanish completely. I would not waste my time on workarounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do it by.......

```
SELECT CCur(val(your_field_name))
FROM qryProjectData
ORDER BY prj.ProjectDisplayNo;
```

You can use `CDec`, `CSng`, and `CDbl` to covert text datatype to numeric, currency, sign and double..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`CCur`](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/datatype/ccur.php) function like this:

```
SELECT CCur(your_field_name) FROM qryProjectData ORDER BY prj.ProjectDisplayNo;
```

Keep in mind that there are also [`CDec`](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/datatype/cdec.php), [`CSng`](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/datatype/csng.php), and [`CDbl`](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/datatype/cdbl.php) functions as well that work the same way.

Comment: Need to sort that data, I tried with "CCur" function but not sorting.

Comment: Given Error When I put CCur(Value) Directly.

Comment: @aagnee: Never just say that you've got an error - *always* give details of what the error is.

Comment: SELECT * FROM qryProjectData ORDER BY CCur(prj.ProjectDisplayNo)..... given Error like "Data Type mismatch in given criteria"... I solved that problem...by giving `Ccur(val(prj.projectdisplayno))`

Comment: Either clean up your data or check for numerical first:  IIf(IsNumeric([prj].[ProjectDisplayNo]), CCur([prj].[ProjectDisplayNo]),NULL). Or filter out non-numeric values: Where IsNumeric([prj].[ProjectDisplayNo]) = True.